# Integration Error for Spring MVC 4 + Apache Tiles 2 + Thymeleaf 3

Tags: java, spring-mvc, web, thymeleaf, apache-tiles

My team had been working on a project using JSP for a few months.  Recently, we realise the implementation of Thymeleaf could be convenient to our web designer so we've started working on integrating it.  The following is the config of our webapp.

```
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer;
import org.thymeleaf.dialect.IDialect;
import org.thymeleaf.extras.tiles2.dialect.TilesDialect;
import org.thymeleaf.extras.tiles2.spring4.web.configurer.ThymeleafTilesConfigurer;
import org.thymeleaf.extras.tiles2.spring4.web.view.ThymeleafTilesView;
import org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.spring4.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ITemplateResolver;

import com.mycompany.web.MultilanguageMessageSource;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.mycompany")
public class ViewConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    /**
     * auto redirection for trailing slash
     */
    @Bean
    public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping(){
        RequestMappingHandlerMapping mapping = new RequestMappingHandlerMapping();
        mapping.setUseTrailingSlashMatch(true);
        return mapping;
    }


    // view resolvers
    @Bean
    public ITemplateResolver templateResolver(){
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateMode("LEGACYHTML5");
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setCacheable(false);
        resolver.setOrder(0);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver(){
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver =  new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setViewClass(ThymeleafTilesView.class);
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        resolver.setOrder(1);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        Set<IDialect> dialects = new LinkedHashSet<IDialect>();
        dialects.add(new TilesDialect());
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        templateEngine.setAdditionalDialects(dialects); 

        return templateEngine;
    } 

    @Bean
    public TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer() {
        ThymeleafTilesConfigurer configurer = new ThymeleafTilesConfigurer();
        configurer.setDefinitions("/WEB-INF/tiles/tiles-definitions.xml");
//      configurer.setCheckRefresh(true);

        return configurer;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/resources/");
    }

    @Bean
    // for Spring general localization
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        return new MultilanguageMessageSource();
    }

}
```

Such configuration does not work at all, giving following error output in eclipse console:

```
03:28:29 DEBUG filter jar: slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar -> false
03:28:29 DEBUG filter jar: logback-core-1.1.3.jar -> false
Oct 18, 2017 3:28:29 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Oct 18, 2017 3:28:29 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath: [com.mycompany.web.WebAppInitializer@1278f9b]
Oct 18, 2017 3:28:30 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Oct 18, 2017 3:28:30 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.info(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:159)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:285)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4851)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Oct 18, 2017 3:28:30 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
Oct 18, 2017 3:28:30 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/WEB] startup failed due to previous errors
Oct 18, 2017 3:28:30 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Oct 18, 2017 3:28:30 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
03:28:30 INFO  Tomcat 8.0.44 started and listening on port 8081
03:28:30 INFO  WEB runs at:
03:28:30 INFO    http://localhost:8081/WEB
03:28:30 DEBUG Tomcat 8.0.44 started.
Run 'gradle appStop' to stop the server.
```

Following is an extract from my build.gradle:

```
    compile group: 'org.thymeleaf', name: 'thymeleaf', version: '3.0.8.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.thymeleaf', name: 'thymeleaf-spring4', version: '3.0.8.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.thymeleaf.extras', name: 'thymeleaf-extras-tiles2', version: '2.1.1.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.thymeleaf.extras', name: 'thymeleaf-extras-tiles2-spring4', version: '2.1.1.RELEASE'

    compile group: 'org.apache.tiles', name: 'tiles-core', version: '2.2.2'
    compile group: 'org.apache.tiles', name: 'tiles-jsp', version: '2.2.2'
    compile group: 'org.apache.tiles', name: 'tiles-api', version: '2.2.2'
    compile group: 'org.apache.tiles', name: 'tiles-servlet', version: '2.2.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

It(java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log) looks like slf4j logger error. I have faced similar error once because of two different versions of slf4j-api jars in classpath. Check your slf4j dependencies once.